# Toolbar over UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad with a 'Done' Button

Tags: iphone

Looking to add a toolbar over UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad with a 'Done' Button. Has any one seen a good current tutorial? Is this the correct approach?  Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically align a toolbar on top of the iPhone keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158574/programmatically-align-a-toolbar-on-top-of-the-iphone-keyboard)

Answer (score -1):

In rough terms, you'll have a UITextField contained in a view controller. When you tap the field, it will become "first responder" and present a keyboard (you configure the type of the keyboard with the UITextField's text input traits). If your view controller is inside a UINavigationController stack, it'll have a top navbar already and you can specify a "Done" button there using a UIBarButtonItem.

Many of the iPhone Developer Center samples will be relevant, but I'd suggest starting with the UICatalog to get a better idea of how this is all handled.

You can also watch the [Stanford iPhone Application Development course on iTunesU](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/iphone-application-development-winter-2010/id384233225) to get a solid foundation.