# toolbar on top of the keyboard with firstresponder

Tags: iphone, uikeyboard, first-responder

This is a pretty common topic and has many answers out there.

**Situation**: I have a full screen (minus toolbar) UITextView with a UIToolbar at the bottom.  when the UITextView gets first responder I want to have the toolbar slide up with the keyboard and add a "done" button which will dismiss the keyboard.

**So far**: I have this completely working, based on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158574/programatically-align-a-toolbar-on-top-of-the-iphone-keyboard).  Except for the fact that when I put `[textView becomeFirstResponder];` in my `viewDidLoad` then the toolbar doesn't animate. Even though `keyboardWillShow` is called.  Does anyone have any idea?

**Code**:  Just so you don't have to check out the example code this is what is happening:

In viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
   [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
   [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
   [textView becomeFirstResponder];
       [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

In keyboardWillShow:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
NSLog(@"keyboard will show");
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:[[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] intValue]];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:[[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue]];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone 
                                                                            target:self 
                                                                            action:@selector(keyboardDone)];
    NSMutableArray *toolbarItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[toolbar items]];
    [toolbarItems addObject:doneButton];
    [toolbar setItems:toolbarItems];

    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.size.height -= [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height;
    self.view.frame = frame;
     [UIView commitAnimations];
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving the `-becomeFirstResponder` call to `-viewWillAppear:animated:` or `-viewDidAppear:animated:`. I think `-viewDidLoad` is usually called just before the view's actually added to the view hierarchy.

Comment: You are AMAZING! Thank you.  It does not work in -viewWillAppear:animated: but it does with -viewDidAppear:animated.  I didn't know the order in which those loaded, so thank you for teaching me something new today.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your code

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{

    UIToolbar* keyboardDoneButtonView   = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    keyboardDoneButtonView.barStyle     = UIBarStyleBlack;
    keyboardDoneButtonView.translucent  = YES;
    keyboardDoneButtonView.tintColor    = nil;
    [keyboardDoneButtonView sizeToFit];

    UIBarButtonItem* doneButton    = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered  target:self action:@selector(doneBtnTapped:)];

    // I put the spacers in to push the doneButton to the right side of the picker view
    UIBarButtonItem *spacer1    = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace 
                                                                                target:nil action:nil];

    // I put the spacers in to push the doneButton to the right side of the picker view
    UIBarButtonItem *spacer    = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace 
                                                                               target:nil action:nil];

    [keyboardDoneButtonView setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer, spacer1, doneButton, nil]];

    // Plug the keyboardDoneButtonView into the text field...
    textView.inputAccessoryView = keyboardDoneButtonView;

    return YES;
}

- (void)doneBtnTapped:(id)sender {
     [yourTextView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

And its all done...