# Display a view when keyboard is visible

Tags: iphone, iphone-softkeyboard

Generally when the key board is visible some apps display a view on the top of keyboard with buttons like Done, Auto fill, .. etc
My Question is :
Is this provided by Apple or We have to create and use it.
Thank You in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is somewhere in the middle. You do have to create it yourself, but Apple provides support for it. See [Programmatically align a toolbar on top of the iPhone keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158574/programatically-align-a-toolbar-on-top-of-the-iphone-keyboard)