# Hide toolbar above iPhone keyboard, PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova, keyboard, toolbar

I'm developing a iPhone app using PhoneGap. In the app there is a page contains only one textarea for user's input. As there is no other input field on this page, I want to hide the toolbar above the keyboard to give user more free space. Is there any way to do so? using javascript

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether this is directly possible with phonegap API but you can change this behavior with native code by writing a PhoneGap plugin to do that.

Refer below links for more detail (they are not exact but will give you the required detail):

[Programmatically align a toolbar on top of the iPhone keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158574/programatically-align-a-toolbar-on-top-of-the-iphone-keyboard)

http://gabriel-tips.blogspot.in/2011/05/input-accessory-view-how-to-add-extra.html

Comment: thanks! It's a good idea. Unfortunately I know only a little about Object-c. But I'll try it, as it seems the only option I got.

Comment: i have a basic phonegap-ios plugin structure at following gist which might help you - https://gist.github.com/1675595

Answer (score 4):

you can Hide it by adding this to config.xml:

```
<preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="true"/>
```

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/config_ref_index.md.html#The%20config.xml%20File

Answer (score 1):

Try this cordova plugin
https://github.com/don/KeyboardToolbarRemover

Answered on this duplicate thread too [Phonegap iOS6: Proper solution to Remove form assistant bar (prev, next, done)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850985/phonegap-ios6-proper-solution-to-remove-form-assistant-bar-prev-next-done/14478608#14478608)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way. This guy has done it by making modifications in the AppDelegate.m. You can find description at this [link](http://ios-blog.co.uk/articles/tutorials/rich-text-editing-a-simple-start-part-1/) under bonus code section.
You can also refer the code for same developed by Kerri Shotts [Code Here](https://github.com/photokandyStudios/GreekInterlinearBible/blob/master/GreekInterlinearBible/Classes/AppDelegate.m#L83)

Now that the done button is gone i am trying to figure out how to make the keyboard disappear. This will be everybody's next step.