# How to find the responder that is returning YES to canPerformAction:withSender:

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebview

I need to disable the Define menu item from the edit menu on a UIWebView. This is supposed to be done by implementing `canPerformAction:withSender:` and returning NO for the items to disable. Even though these are private items it seems like I should be able to return YES for the items I want to keep and NO for everything else (as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614465/how-do-you-really-remove-copy-from-uimenucontroller)).

However this is not working. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/canPerformAction:withSender:) says that

> If no responder in the responder chain returns YES, the menu command is disabled. Note that if your class returns NO for a command, another responder further up the responder chain may still return YES, enabling the command.

It seems that this must be the reason this isn't working. How do I find which responder is returning YES?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I figured this out with this function which recursively goes through the subviews and logs whether they are first responder.

```
- (void) logResponderInfo: (UIView *)view 
{
    NSLog(@"%@ %@", NSStringFromClass(view.class), view.isFirstResponder ? @"yes" : @"no");

    for (UIView *sub in view.subviews) {
        [self logResponderInfo:sub];
    }
}
```

Which I called from my `canPerformAction:withSender:` function

```
[self logResponderInfo:self.webView];
```

This wrote out to the logs

```
2013-11-18 11:35:56.100 Testing[44593:a0b] CDVCordovaView no
2013-11-18 11:35:56.100 Testing[44593:a0b] _UIWebViewScrollView no
2013-11-18 11:35:56.101 Testing[44593:a0b] UIWebBrowserView yes
2013-11-18 11:35:56.101 Testing[44593:a0b] UITextSelectionView no
2013-11-18 11:35:56.102 Testing[44593:a0b] UIView no
2013-11-18 11:35:56.102 Testing[44593:a0b] UIImageView no
2013-11-18 11:35:56.103 Testing[44593:a0b] UIImageView no
2013-11-18 11:35:56.103 Testing[44593:a0b] UIActivityIndicatorView no
2013-11-18 11:35:56.104 Testing[44593:a0b] UIImageView no
```

which told me that the first responder was in fact UIWebBrowserView.

Comment: Awesome investigation, thanks.  Note that http://stackoverflow.com/a/9048973/294884 using a non-app-store approach, you can override it, sort of.

Comment: Also note: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033292/ios-7-uiwebview-keyboard-issue

Comment: Thanks. The solution I ultimately used was based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14479217/1873374), using code from [here](https://gist.github.com/bjhomer/2048571).