# Objective c toolbar above keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programatically align a toolbar on top of the iPhone keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158574/programatically-align-a-toolbar-on-top-of-the-iphone-keyboard)

I'm trying to understand, how to do the toolbar above the keyboard as in this image
[image]

Is this a native ios view I can use?

Comment: http://gabriel-tips.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/input-accessory-view-how-to-add-extra.html http://idebuggerman.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/uitoolbar-for-keyboard-with.html please do some research before posting questions - there's loads of info out there.

Comment: And it's not related to objective-C but to Cocoa Touch.

Comment: @Cyrille cocoa touch IS [a framework of] objective-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only one keyword to search: `inputAccessoryView`.

Comment: thanks, do you know how to get this toolbar style and hoe to add the buttons?

Answer (score 2):

This is something you can do with the `inputAccessoryView` have a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/inputAccessoryView

Comment: Thanks for this - I've been writing my own keyboard toolbar stuff for ages, never occurred to me that one might be built in! Even old dogs can learn new tricks...