# How do I show the keyboard with a view above it?

Tags: ios, swift

When a user taps on a button, I'd like the keyboard to pop up (which is easy), but I want a view that goes up along with it (sticking to the top of the keyboard).  This view will be have a "send a message.." textfield. When the user pushes done, I want the keyboard to go away along with the view.

How do I make this view "stick" to the keyboard?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

UITextFields have a property called inputAccessoryView

[- Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html)

[- Relevant Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158574/programmatically-align-a-toolbar-on-top-of-the-iphone-keyboard)

This will pin whatever view you assign as that textfield's inputAccessoryView to the top of the keyboard.

Something important from the answer in that link to remember:

> Note that the view you use should neither be in the view hierarchy elsewhere, nor should you add it to some superview, this is done for you.

Answer (score 0):

go to your storyboard and add a view(lets call it topKeyboardView) at the bottom of your viewController. and give it the following constraints:

bottom space to bottom layout = 0

### [image: bottom space to bottom layout = 0]

and then add the textfield*(i prefer using textView to make it change its height when the message gets too long...)*
and your button(send) on top of topKeyboardView.

lets code now..
go to your viewController.swift and add an IBOutlet to your textField and button and add this function:

```
    //this is will tell if the keyboard hidden or not
    func addKeyboardNotifications() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

    // MARK:- Notification
    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        print("keyboard is up")
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        print("keyboard is down")
    }
```

in your `viewDidLoad` call the function:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        addKeyboardNotifications()
   }
```

run it...

Comment: This is far more complicated than needed. Simply set the text field's or text view's `inputAccessoryView`. That's it.